# Creating GIF with different speed

Tags: python, imagemagick, gif

I have created a series of plots and want to make GIF of them with different speeds.

I know how to create a GIF using imagemagick with this command:  magick *jpeg -delay 10 name.gif .

However I want some of the jpeg files to be displayed longer than others, how can I achieve that?

Additionaly maybe it is easier to do it inside python? I have a list of figures there from which I want to create this GIF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the delay individually prior to loading the image:

```
magick -delay 30 red.png -delay 80 green.png -delay 99 blue.png anim.gif
```

[image]

Check the delays, offsets, disposition like this:

```
magick identify -format "%f[%s] canvas=%Wx%H size=%wx%h offset=%X%Y %D %Tcentisecs\n"  anim.gif
anim.gif[0] canvas=100x100 size=100x100 offset=+0+0 Undefined 30centisecs
anim.gif[1] canvas=100x100 size=100x100 offset=+0+0 Undefined 80centisecs
anim.gif[2] canvas=100x100 size=100x100 offset=+0+0 Undefined 99centisecs
```

Note that, since `-delay` is a **setting**, it remains set until changed, so the first 4 frames inherit 10 centiseconds of delay and the remainder get 25 centiseconds:

```
magick -delay 10 frame-[0-3].jpg -delay 25 frame-[4-7].jpg  anim.gif
identify -format "%f[%s] canvas=%Wx%H size=%wx%h offset=%X%Y %D %Tcentisecs\n"  anim.gif
anim.gif[0] canvas=100x100 size=100x100 offset=+0+0 Undefined 10centisecs
anim.gif[1] canvas=100x100 size=100x100 offset=+0+0 Undefined 10centisecs
anim.gif[2] canvas=100x100 size=100x100 offset=+0+0 Undefined 10centisecs
anim.gif[3] canvas=100x100 size=100x100 offset=+0+0 Undefined 10centisecs
anim.gif[4] canvas=100x100 size=100x100 offset=+0+0 Undefined 25centisecs
anim.gif[5] canvas=100x100 size=100x100 offset=+0+0 Undefined 25centisecs
anim.gif[6] canvas=100x100 size=100x100 offset=+0+0 Undefined 25centisecs
anim.gif[7] canvas=100x100 size=100x100 offset=+0+0 Undefined 25centisecs
```

Carrying on from there, if you want to do something more complicated, I would resort to `gifsicle`, so say you wanted what I had above but with frame 4 having a 17 centisecond delay:

```
# Change delay to 17 on frame 4 only
gifsicle -b anim.gif "#0-3" -d17 "#4" --same-delay "#5-" 

# Check again
anim.gif[0] canvas=100x100 size=100x100 offset=+0+0 Undefined 10centisecs
anim.gif[1] canvas=100x100 size=100x100 offset=+0+0 Undefined 10centisecs
anim.gif[2] canvas=100x100 size=100x100 offset=+0+0 Undefined 10centisecs
anim.gif[3] canvas=100x100 size=100x100 offset=+0+0 Undefined 10centisecs
anim.gif[4] canvas=100x100 size=100x100 offset=+0+0 Undefined 17centisecs    <--- HERE
anim.gif[5] canvas=100x100 size=100x100 offset=+0+0 Undefined 25centisecs
anim.gif[6] canvas=100x100 size=100x100 offset=+0+0 Undefined 25centisecs
anim.gif[7] canvas=100x100 size=100x100 offset=+0+0 Undefined 25centisecs
```

**Keywords**: ImageMagick, gifsicle, delay, set delay individually, individual frame, centiseconds.

Comment: Thank you, I have 2 questions! If I wanted to make for instance 5 jpegs with speed 30, could I do this with one delay instance? Also if I wanted to include with speed 10 all other jpegs apart from those I already used, how could I do that?

Comment: I added some further details - please have another look.